# What is the best way to insert a character into a string in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, substr

What is the best way to insert a character into a string at multiple positions in Perl? I have a string in which I have removed any non-numeric characters. After that, I want to insert a dash at the 4th position and 8th position starting from the end. You guessed it, I'm modifying all inputted phone numbers so that they all have the same format: XXX-XXX-XXXX

```
$number =~ s/[^0-9]//g;
substr($number, -4, 0, '-');
substr($number, -8, 0, '-');
```

Is there a regex that can do the above code but in a single line? Is there something more efficient out there that I don't know about?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `s/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/$1-$2-$3/`

Comment: Do you really need `+` in the allowed characters?

Comment: @Miller I guess not. Will edit now. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This also works:

```
$number =~ s/(...)(...)(....)$/$1-$2-$3/
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about performance, but `unpack`-and-`join` also works:

```
join( '-', unpack 'A3 A3 A4', $number )
```

Comment: A quick benchmark shows this to be twice as fast as the regex solution on average. `unpack` is king when it comes to fixed-width data. :-)